# Boolean parameter returning false after to be set to true in a method

Tags: c#, parameters, boolean, flags

I have a form which calls another form that will do an action, and if that action is done, a flag that I put as parameter in parent form will be set to true in child form, but if the action is not done, the flag keep false.

The code in parent form:

```
bool flag = false;
new ChildForm(flag).ShowDialog();
if(flag)
{
//some code that depends on that flag be true
}
```

The code in child form:

```
bool flag;
public ChildForm(bool flag)
{
InitializeComponent();
this.flag = flag;
}
private SomeMethod()
{
//some code
flag = true;
this.Close();
}
```

Debugging it I saw that after the flag is set to true in child form, the flag in parent form is also true, but after the child form is closed and program back to execute parent forms code, the flag turns back to be false.

What's happening?

Comment: In this codesample it is impossible, that if(flag) is entering

Comment: @BennoDual how? The method in child form sets flag to true.

Comment: It set the flag in the ChildForm to true - this has no impact on the varaible in the parent form.

Comment: @BennoDual As I said, the debugger showed me that the parent flag was true, this is why I did not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *flag* variable is passed by value to the constructor of *ChildForm* and assigned to private variable also called *flag*. This means that any change to the private variable will not affect the original one.

To solve this issue you would need to declare *ChildForm* variable as public and use it in the original method.

```
public boolean flag;
public ChildForm(boolean flag)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.flag = flag;
}
private SomeMethod()
{
  //some code
  flag = true;
  this.Close();
}
```

And change the original method as follows

```
boolean flag = false;
var form = new ChildForm(flag);
form.ShowDialog();
if(form.flag)
{
//some code that depends on that flag be true
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-value-type-parameters for more information on passing variables by value/reference.

Comment: As I said, the debug showed me that the parent flag was true, this is why I did not understand. You solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it seemed to change to `true` in the parent form is probably just a side-effect of viewing it in the debugger. It doesn't actually change it to `true`.

If you want to read the value from the child form, you'll need to make it accessible.

Parent form:

```
var c = new ChildForm();
c.ShowDialog();
if (c.Flag)
{
    //some code that depends on that flag be true
}
```

Child form:

```
public bool Flag { get; private set; }
public ChildForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private SomeMethod()
{
    //some code
    Flag = true;
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: That side-effect in debugging just cheated me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on this way:

```
public class ChildForm {
    public ChildForm(bool flag) {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.Flag = flag;
    }

    private SomeMethod() {
        //some code
        this.Flag = true;
        this.Close();
    }
    public bool Flag {get;}
}

public class ParentForm {
   public void Foo() {
      bool flag = false;
      var child = new ChildForm(flag);
      child.ShowDialog();
      if(child.Flag) {
          //some code that depends on that flag be true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: As I said, the debug showed me that the parent flag was true, this is why I did not understand. This worked, thanks